# Android Emulator - camera flickering

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am using Android Studio and its emulator. I have created device Pixel 3 XL with Android 9.0. I have to test one application, where I have to scan QR code. I have set phone camera to my webcam, unfortunately there is huge flickering, when I want to scan it. Web cam LED on my notebook is also blinking (ON, OFF, ON, OFF....). I have also tried use Virtual Scene, but when I run it, it is also flickering.

Could someone help me where is the problem? Or is there any other way, how to scan QR code?